# Distinct ways for stacking a NxNxN cube with K different unit cells

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, coloring

Let's say we have to build a cube of shape N x N x N (in some units) by stacking smaller cubes each of size 1 x 1 x 1 (in some units). Each of the smaller cubes (unit cubes) come in one of the K distinct colors and we have sufficient supply of cubes of each color. How many distinct ways are there in which we can stack these cubes to form the bigger cube?

Bigger cubes which can be rotated or mirrored to each other are not considered distinct.

PS: I came across several links on the stackexchange but none of them are general enough. Very curious to know if there is a general formulation which can help solve this problem. Also interested in knowing what happens when we increase the dimensionality in the problem i.e. for N x N x N x N hypercube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should know is [the automorphism group of the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry#The_isometries_of_the_cube), plus [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

See if you can figure it out by assembling information from these references.

Comment: I am not very familiar with group theory and theory of symmetry. So, finding it a bit difficult to grasp. What would you recommend as a priliminary reference to read so that I maybe able to put these things together? Thanks !

Comment: I'd suggest that you start with a simpler example. Perhaps understanding the example given in the "Burnside's lemma" wiki page would be useful. Also you might want to start with the basics of group theory (need not be too deep), especially the notion of a group acting on a set. These are available in many standard textbooks. This of course requires some investigation of time and energy, but it's a very useful tool, so I think it definitely worths the effort. It'll be a lot of fun when you finally manage to solve this problem and many more similar ones!

Comment: This seems quite useful - thanks! I think I understand the process now. Only thing I need to figure out now are all the isometries of this NxNxN cube. Is there some way to systematically enumerate them ? That'll greatly reduce the complexity of the problem !

Comment: This is more or less described in the first link in the answer (but perhaps not very well written). See also http://kociemba.org/math/symmetric.htm

Comment: Yep this is more clear. Also, is there a way we can accommodate periodicity? So, essentially a 1D analogue will be - sequence [1,2,3] is same as sequence [2,3,1].

Comment: That is basically the action of the group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: This is amazing! I also realized that I can put a lower bound on the number as (K^(N^3)) / |number_of_isometries| - just want to verify it with you if this is indeed a correct statement?

Comment: Yes, of course it's a valid lower bound.